# Who exactly issues the confidential identity in Corda?

Tags: corda

How is X.509 certificate for a confidential identity signed? Does the node signs it with it's node certificate? Or is it signed with node's well-known signing identity?

How is it avoided that the certification chain can not be followed back from the signature created by the confidential signing identity? For instance, in the cash usecase where historic states back to the issuer have to be presented in order to be able to validate cash transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node's well-known identity issues and signs certificates for each one of its confidential identities.

It only shares the certificate chain linking a confidential identity back to its well-known identity on a need-to-know basis.

If a node inspects a transaction chain where a confidential identity has been used for which they have not received the certificate chain, the node will simply see an anonymous public key that they cannot link to a well-known identity.